# Converting some Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, arraylist, code-translation

This is the line of code I am having trouble converting:

```
Vector3 n1 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.X - 1);
```

I am not sure what this translates to in c# as I have tried quite a few things. I think it may also be due to a problem with my lists:

```
class Model
{
    public List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> normals = new List<Vector3>();
    public List<Face> faces = new List<Face>();

}
```

They were supposed to be:

```
class Model
{
    public List<Vector3> vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3>();
    public List<Vector3> normals = new ArrayList<Vector3>();
    public List<Face> faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

}
```

I dont know what ListArray translates to in c# either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Never heard of `ListArray` in Java. Is it a proprietory class? Do you mean `ArrayList`?

Comment: [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Java               C#
------------    --------
List<T>      is IList<T>   // Interface
ArrayList<T> is List<T>    // Class implementing the interface
```

You can translate your code like this:

```
class Model
{
    public IList<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    public IList<Vector3> normals = new List<Vector3>();
    public IList<Face> faces = new List<Face>();
}
```

Java's `get` becomes C#'s [*indexer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx), so

```
Vector3 n1 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.X - 1);
```

becomes

```
Vector3 n1 = m.normals[(int)face.normal.X - 1];
```